# Where to implement Picasso in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, picasso

I am using AsyncTask to get data from database and load into a ListView. I want to use Picasso to resize the image before loading into the ListView. Only problem is that I don't know where to implement it.

```
public void getListFromDb(){
Cursor res = myDb.ViewAll();
startManagingCursor(res);


//Map cursor from db to viewFields
String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4, DatabaseHelper.COL_5, DatabaseHelper.COL_6};
int[] toViewIDS = new int[]{R.id.viewName, R.id.viewAddress, R.id.viewPostcode, R.id.viewType, R.id.imageView};

//Create SimpleCursorAdaptor with null cursor
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, null, fromFieldNames, toViewIDS, 0);
// Set adaptor for listView
myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);

new AsyncTask<SimpleCursorAdapter, Void, Cursor>() {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mSimpleCursorAdapter;
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(SimpleCursorAdapter... params) {
        // Save cursorAdapter to use in postExecute
        this.mSimpleCursorAdapter = params[0];
        // Load cursor on background thread with search function
           return myDb.ViewAll();
        }
    }
```

Where can I implement Picasso to resize the images before it displays it in the ListView.

Thanks

Comment: The load method for Picasso already runs Async, you don't need to run it in the AsyncTask. Anyway, just use it like you would anywhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use Picasso with `SimpleCursorAdapter`. You may have to write a custom list adapter. Inside that you can bind the ImageViews using Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso already have the `resize` method implemented and it already runs in backbround, so you don't need to implement async task for it.

```
Picasso
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
.into(imageViewResize);
```

See the [docs](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: I implemented it before the AsyncTask but I am getting this error.  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4

Comment: This issue is not about Picasso , and is out of this topic . If my question helped him on ` resize` with Picasso , consider it finished and create another topic about this error in particular .

Answer (score 0):

Picasso library will do it's operations in background using asyncTask.
according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21515718/4983685). you just need to load images in your [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)'s [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

```
     Picasso.with(context) 
 .load(url)
 .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
 .error(R.drawable.ic_error) 
 .resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size,R.dimen.list_detail_image_size).centerInside()
// Also .resize(Width , Height)

.into(imgView);
```